# Getting numerous errors with Vulkan Memory Allocator, "'(': illegal token on right side of '::'"

Tags: c++, vulkan

I had this issue, come up when first trying to get Vulkan Memory Allocator(VMA) integrated into my program, and it was quite frustrating as nowhere in the VMA documentation could I find such an error. After looking in the `vk_mem_alloc.h` file I found that the issue was caused because `vk_mem_alloc.h` uses `std::max` and `std::min` which have conflicts with `windows.h` which I was also using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is quite easy, all you must do is call the `#include "vk_mem_alloc.h"` before the `#include <windows.h>`, but it's something that an amateur like me can get easily hung up on, so I thought I'd document my difficulty here for others attempting to learn this daunting API.

Comment: or include windows with `#define NOMINMAX`?